# left binary search in python

Tags: python, search, binary

For e.g if input is [1,2,3,3,4,4,5] and I search 3, it should return 2 as index 2 is
the left most occurance of 3.

In [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], I search for 1, you should return 0.

how can we write the function to traverse back in binary search?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how best to frame a question.

Comment: You should use `list.index` function. That is how it works by default.

Comment: [`bisect.bisect_left`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left).

Comment: @user2357112 Why not `list.index`?!?

Comment: @thefourtheye: `list.index` isn't a binary search.

Comment: @user2357112 Why do we need binary search for this case? He hasn't mentioned that the data is sorted. He just says `left most occurence`

Comment: @thefourtheye: Considering that "binary search" appears in both the title and the question body, and that both example inputs are sorted, I'm pretty sure he wants a binary search.

Comment: how to use bisect.bisect_left?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What didn't you understand?

Comment: yes but can you give an example for that? @user2357112

Comment: `bisect.bisect_left([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 2)`

Answer (score 0):

## you can go with this code for finding the leftmost element in a left binary search

```
def left_binary_search(input, value):
    try:
        if (type(input).__name__ != 'list') or (type(value).__name__ != 'int'):
            raise TypeError

    low = 0
    high = len(input) - 1
    check = (low + high) // 2
    q = False
    l1 = []
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if input[mid] > value:
            high = mid - 1
        elif input[mid] < value:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            if mid > check:
                return -1
            else:
                q = True
                l1.append(mid)
                high = mid
                if low == high:
                    return min(l1)
    if q == False:
        return -1
    return min(l1)
except TypeError:
    print("invalid type")
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the left most index of the element or -1 if the element is not found.

```
def left_binary_search(arr, value):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    index = -1

    while (low <= high):

        mid = (low + high) // 2

        if arr[mid] == value:
            index = mid
            high = mid - 1
        elif arr[mid] < value:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1

    return index
```